# Message is not showing on facebook app invitation?

Tags: android, facebook

Hello every i am working app where i have to send invitation of my app to my facebook friend.
My invitation successfully send but message is not showing to my friend whom i send the app request.

i follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217911/facebook-api-and-send-invite-to-more-than-one-friend-in-android) question which help in that but message is not showing to that user whom i send the app request.

here is my code:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("to", fb2);
                parameters.putString("message", "hello app ...");
                Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
                mFacebook.dialog(getParent(), "apprequests", parameters, new Facebook.DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                        Toast.makeText(getParent(), "Invitation has been send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: The message is not shown for requests that are invites.

Comment: @CBro so is there any way that i can send message along with the invitation to the my friends..